# uploading files in js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm using below method to upload files to laravel backend

```
setFile(id, e) {
                let self = this;
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
                reader.onload = function () {
                    console.log(reader.result);
                    self.documentArray.forEach(function (element) {
                        if (id == element.id && reader.result) {
                            element.file = reader.result;
                            element.file_browse_name = e.target.files[0].name;
                        }
                    });
                };
                reader.onerror = function (error) {
                    console.log('Error: ', error);
                };
            },
```

but when i select a file larger than 5mb or around, it doesn't add the element to the relevant object of the documentArray but it logs the result in console, so i cant add validation on backend. please give me a way to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is with your PHP settings. Check your upload_max_filesize and your post_max_size

Comment: @madusanka You're welcome. Juste be aware that it also can be tricky to set these values high. Many large post request can stress out your server. If you upload images you can better resize and compress them with javascript before sending them. Also with javascript you can check the file size and show an alert when the file is bigger then your post limit or max file size

Comment: much appreciate